# mongoose find json inside layers json

Tags: javascript, mongoose

queueModel.js

```
   var mongoose = require('mongoose');
   var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
   var queueSchema = Schema({
        title: String,
        description: String,
        abc:{
            a1: String,
            b1: String,
            c1: String
        },
    });
    var Queue = mongoose.model('Queue', queueSchema);
    module.exports = Queue;
```

api1.js

```
Queue.findOne({ title: "zzzz"} ).exec((err, data) => {
          if (err) console.log(err)
          else console.log(data)
});
```

result is data ...

api2.js (problem)

```
Queue.findOne({ title: "zzzz", abc:{a1: "aaaa"} } ).exec((err, data) => {
      if (err) console.log(err)
      else console.log(data)
});
```

Why is it null?

I want to use a1 condition.

Ask a Solution.

Do not modify the schema.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Queue.findOne({ title: "zzzz", "abc.a1": "aaaa"} } ).exec((err, data) => {
  if (err) console.log(err)
  else console.log(data)
});
```

To filter on the `abc` you need to do `abc.a1` as the field.